# Set Folder, Subfolder and File Permission Set-ACL Powershell Script. Setting File Inherititance does not work

Tags: xml, powershell, file-permissions, psexec, powershell-cmdlet

I need some help with my Powershell Script.
my customer got a huge directory and i need to change the Security Settings.

I made this code below and It works but i got one problem:
The inheritance on the Files does not work so the Security permissions on any File in the directory is not set.

Maybe Someone will find my error.

XML File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Pfade>
    <pfad name="E:\Share\TEST">
        <gruppe name="Domain Admins">
            <rechte>FullControl</rechte>
            <aktion>allow</aktion>
            <rechtsetzen>Add</rechtsetzen>
        </gruppe>
        <gruppe name="gruppe1">
            <rechte>Modify</rechte>
            <aktion>allow</aktion>
            <rechtsetzen>Add</rechtsetzen>
        </gruppe>
        <gruppe name="gruppe2">
            <rechte>Modify</rechte>
            <aktion>allow</aktion>
            <rechtsetzen>Add</rechtsetzen>
        </gruppe>
        <gruppe name="gruppe3">
            <rechte>Modify</rechte>
            <aktion>allow</aktion>
            <rechtsetzen>Add</rechtsetzen>
        </gruppe>
        <gruppe name="gruppe4">
            <rechte>Modify</rechte>
            <aktion>allow</aktion>
            <rechtsetzen>Add</rechtsetzen>
        </gruppe>
        <gruppe name="gruppe5">
            <rechte>Modify</rechte>
            <aktion>allow</aktion>
            <rechtsetzen>Add</rechtsetzen>
        </gruppe>
        <gruppe name="SYSTEM">
            <rechte>FullControl</rechte>
            <aktion>allow</aktion>
            <rechtsetzen>Add</rechtsetzen>
        </gruppe>
    </pfad>
</Pfade>
```

PowerShell:

```bsh
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
cd $dir
# Einlesen des XML-Dokuments im aktuellen Skriptpfad (!)
$doc = [XML](Get-Content -Path struktur.xml)

#### Start TAKEOWN
$Remotesystem = "\\server1"
$Adminuser = "domain\admin"
$yes = "Y"
$log = "c:\Users\admin\Desktop\log.txt"


psexec $Remotesystem 
TAKEOWN /S $Remotesystem /F $doc.Pfade.pfad.name /D $yes /R >> $log
#### End TAKEOWN

$inherit = [system.security.accesscontrol.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$propagation = [system.security.accesscontrol.PropagationFlags]"None"

$doc.Pfade.pfad | ForEach-Object {
    $FolderName = $_.name
    $_.gruppe | ForEach-Object {
        $pathrecht  = $_.rechte
        $pathaktion = $_.aktion
        $pathrechts = $_.rechtsetzen
        $pathgruppe = $_.name
        $acl = Get-Acl $FolderName
        $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False)
        $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($pathgruppe, $pathrecht, $inherit, $propagation, $pathaktion)
        switch ($pathrechts) {
        Add {$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)}
        Delete {$acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($rule)}
        }
        Set-Acl $FolderName $acl
        echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~">>log.txt
        $date = Get-Date -format dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm:ss
        $date>>log.txt
        Get-Acl $FolderName | select Path, Owner, Group, AccessToString | Format-List >>log.txt
        echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~">>log.txt
    }
}
    echo "########################################################################################">>log.txt
    echo "########################################################################################">>log.txt
    echo "########################################################################################">>log.txt
cd $dir
```

The Permissions on the Folder and Subfolder is exactly what i want [subfolderpermisson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuAei.png)
but the permission on the file [filepermission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Sgv.png) direct ist not set why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it.
The Files where Protectet bacause of my fault:

```bsh
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False)
```

i needed to Change the SetAccessRuleProtection to this:

```bsh
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($False, $True)
```

Thanks to thudbutt for that [Explain for beginners the ACL object property "SetAccessRuleProtection" in PowerShell with examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787843/explain-for-beginners-the-acl-object-property-setaccessruleprotection-in-power)